# What does "factors through" mean in $K[K^t] \xrightarrow{\phi} K[K^n] \xrightarrow{\rho} K[V]$ factors through $K[W]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coordinate-systems

What does "factors through" mean in $K[K^t] \xrightarrow{\phi} K[K^n] \xrightarrow{\rho} K[V]$ factors through $K[W]$ $(*)$?

$V \subseteq K^n, W \subseteq K^t$ are varieties, $K[V] = K[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(V)$ is the coordinate ring of $V$ and similarly for $K[W], \rho$ is the restriction map, $\Phi : K^n \to K^t$ is a polynomial map, and $\phi : K[K^t] \to K[K^n]$ sends $f \to f \circ \Phi.$

The problem is to prove $(*)$ is equivalent to $\Phi$ restricting to a map $\Phi|_V \to W,$ which is equivalent to $\Phi(V) \subseteq W.$ As the previous part of the problem asked to prove $\Phi(V) \subseteq W \Leftrightarrow \phi(I(W)) \subseteq I(V),$ I suspect $(*)$ is equivalent to $\phi(I(W)) \subseteq I(V),$ which is equivalent to $\phi(I(W)) \subseteq \ker \rho.$ This is starting to look like exact sequences, but I don't want to waste any time under the assumption we can work backwards to guess what "factors through" means.

Comment: Generally in category-theoretic language, "Every $f:A\to B$ factors through $g$" means (if $g:A\to C$) that there exists a map $h:C\to B$ with $f=h\circ g$, or (if $g:C\to B$) there exists $h:A\to C$ with $f=g\circ h$

Comment: @FShrike That definition doesn't fit because $K[W]$ is not a map.

Comment: Sure, the other meaning which I missed it is: "Every $f:A\to B$ factors through $C$" means there exists always $g:A\to C,h:C\to B$ with $f=h\circ g$

Comment: @FShrike this looks like an answer - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: I don’t know any algebraic geometry so I wouldn’t feel confident doing so @KReiser

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments by [FShrike](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/815585/fshrike), saying a map $f:X\to Y$ "factors through $Z$" means that there are maps $g:X\to Z$ and $h:Z\to Y$ such that $f=h\circ g$. In your case, you're being asked to show that the composite map $K[K^t]\to K[K^n]\to K[V]$ can also be written $K[K^t]\to K[W]\to K[V]$.